# ¿Cómo puedo crear una expresion regular para identificar palabras reservadas?

Tags: java, regex

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class reservadas {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println ("Empezamos el programa");
                System.out.println ("Por favor introduzca una cadena por teclado:");
                String entradaTeclado2 = "";
                Scanner entradaEscaner = new Scanner (System.in); //Creación de un objeto Scanner
                entradaTeclado2 = entradaEscaner.nextLine (); //Invocamos un método sobre el objeto Scanner
              String  palabras[] = {"abstract","assert","boolean","break","byte","casa","catch","char","class","conts","continue","default","do"};
               String error = "error";
               String bin = "bin";


              for (String palabra : palabras) {
                if (palabra.equals(entradaTeclado2)) {
                     System.out.println("Palabra reservada");
                     break;
                }else {
                    if (palabra != (entradaTeclado2)) {
                        System.out.println("no reservada");

                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de como hacerlo, ¿pero para que lo necesitas? Quizá estás buscando crear una utilidad que el propio java tiene incluida Puedes encontrar la lista de palabras reservadas en la documentación oficial, así como en que versión se añaden o si están Deprecated:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: hola m.alvarez, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio, asi como [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Has de pulsar en [edit] para añadir lo que has intentado hasta ahora, mejorar la explicacion (ya que va en el cuerpo de la pregunta, no en el titulo ) y explicar tambien qué problemas **concretos** tuviste . Un saludo

Comment: Hola @javier-enciso. Creo que para abrir esta pregunta te faltaría simplemente añadir algo de introducción al cuerpo de la pregunta y no dejar sólo el código. Por ejempo, algo como: `Intento validar la entrada de un usuario y buscar palabras reservadas. El problema es que voy línea a línea y el "equals" me compara la palabra con toda la línea. Lo que necesitaría es una expresión regular para validar/encontrar las palabras reservadas en un string/línea` (por ejemplo )